# How we can stop a program at certain time in a day@15:30pm everyday...?(It's running every 1 minute)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Anyone help me to get code for below conditions...

I would like to run job1 and job2 for every 2 and 3 seconds, and job3 @17:31pm daily once only..
*But,job1 and job2 should start@9:30pm in a day..and should stop@17:30pm...!

## Below is my code to update according to above conditions...!

```
import schedule
import time

def job1():
   print("I'm working...")
def job2():
   print("I'm not working...")
def job3():
   print("I'll not work...")

schedule.every(2).seconds.do(job1) #For Every 2 seconds
schedule.every(5).seconds.do(job2) #For Every 3 Seconds


schedule.every().day.at("17:28").do(job3) #Once in a day

while True:
   schedule.run_pending()
   time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual [here](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#main-interface) you can [cancel](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#schedule.Scheduler.cancel_job) a job.

Inside your `while True:`:

- check the current time
- if it is before 9:30 cancel `job1` and `job2` if currently scheduled
- if it is after 17:30 cancel `job1` and `job2` if currently scheduled

---

You should also fix 17:28 for `job3` to 17:31 if it should run at this time ... and it would probably better if you use a OS-scheduler to start this program of yours at 9:29 and exit it once `job3` is done - that is better then letting your program run each second in between 17:31 and 9:30 when nothing is going to be scheduled anyway...